# Software to create a user-friendly web UI to view and insert data into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, user-interface

I have been using phpmyadmin on WAMPserver to manage MYSQL database.
However I wish to create another interface where my other users can access the database to INSERT and SELECT data only.(I know this can be done with phpmyadmin but I was thinking if I can design my own platform)
There should be a log in for the users(as well as one with admin privileges)
Thanks!

Comment: Basic HTML forms that POST to a PHP script would be easy to do, is supported by many web hosting companies or is easy to set up (the LAMP stack)

Comment: Only INSERT and SELECT, no UPDATE? Also no ORDER BY or paging?

Comment: Or `JOIN, GROUP BY, LIMIT`, etc ?